# Performance comparison:Array of Array vs Array of Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, object

I sometimes need a list model to store a lot of different elements with a common structure, for example when using a list of 2D coordinates or a list of RGB values.

Taking the RGB values example, I have two ways to store each element in an Array:

```
// using small Array
var arrayOfArray = [[0, 0, 0], [110, 120, 130], ...]

// using Object
var arrayOfObject = [{r: 0, g: 0, b: 0}, {r: 110, g: 120, b: 130}, ...]
```

Once the array of is defined I need to do some operations: run through each element, get or set a specific value of an element, compare two elements, etc.

However, I am not sure of which method is the best regarding performance. Is it better to use a small Array or to use an Object ?

I have considered using a flat array with typed values (as defined on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays)), which is how [image data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData/data) is stored in a Canvas, but I would prefer one the the strucure above.

I created a [JSPerf test case](https://jsperf.com/small-array-vs-small-object) to compare the two, and the first results (*06/03/19*) are indicating that using an Array of Objects is faster.

Comment: Performance should be measured within the code you're writing. See [Eric Lippert's blog post on "which is faster?"](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Comment: How big these arrays are expected to be? Make sure you do not over-micro-optimize in lose of convenient usage of entities when developing. Also when storing RGB as array it's very easy to get bug where you store values in wrong order

Comment: I have planned to test the performance each time I use this structure @HereticMonkey, but I was wondering if there was a significant difference that I was unaware of.

Comment: @Justinas An array could contains up to a million elements, in case of a large image or a very dense set of points. I might be wrong, but I do not expect bugs if I stick to common convention for array ordering: [x, y] for coordinates, [r, g, b] for colors, etc.

Comment: Well, you tested it on jsPerf, and I'm seeing that they are more or less equivalent. Generally, performance questions don't go over too well on Stack Overflow because there are a *lot* of variables in performance; what browser are they using?, what platform?, what CPU/memory/cache?. So getting the "best" performance will be very difficult to pin down.

Comment: *"but I was wondering if there was a significant difference that I was unaware of"* This is a definite *maybe*. There may be differences in performance based on the Browser, browser version, OS, the exact implemetation of the Data structure (has it 3 properties or 10)? the "data-types" of these prperties, the code that creates and or uses the data-structure. Basically your JSPerf test ain't worth anything. It only benchmarks the performance of the exact test-code. I'd go with objects for the simple reason, the nested data ain't logically a list.